# Has light been used to measure relative velocity?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

[image]
[image]

Here we have 2 lasers. Both are in the same frame of reference as is top box.

Laser #1 sends the light directly through the hole in the top box on one side and the light eventually exits the hole on the opposite side.

However, if the second box was in motion relative to the 2 lasers, this does not mean that the light will pass through both holes in this case. The light path from laser #2 will not bend simply because an object is passing by.Thus the light will make contact within the box at the rear instead.

Has this kind of phenomena ever been used to measure SR properties ?
( Sorry if images are not in sync.)

Comment: I don't understand the question. What phenomenon do you expect to observe here, and why is the light ray bending in the second image?

Comment: The second image illustrates what will NOT happen. Thus as stated, "the light will make contact within the box at the rear instead.".

Comment: Okay. So, what the question? Whether someone has tested if the light actually hits the rear? (Given the speed of light, you'd need very big or very fast boxes for that)

Comment: Yes, ... has this method been practiced in any way at all, thus not being "specifically" limited to the box version of it is the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Has this kind of phenomena ever been used to measure SR properties ?

Yes. A similar apparatus, called a Fizeau apparatus, has been around for a long time... It uses a rotating cog rather than a falling box (for obvious reasons).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau%E2%80%93Foucault_apparatus

EDIT (re comment): 
Yes, lasers can also be used to measure the relative velocity of two bodies. The policeman's "Radar gun" has been replaced with a "Laser gun" with a high resolution timing circuit. See, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIDAR_speed_gun

Comment: Is that apperatus not for measuring the speed of light rather than for using light to measure relative velocities of two bodies?

Comment: yes, but the mechanical principle is similar. See edit for a better example, but less mechanical.